# Sqlite 2 python using a python tempfile

Tags: python, sqlite, temporary-files, pysqlite

I'm experiencing some strange behavior from sqlite using a database stored as a python tempfile. Essentially, querying the sqlite_master table works fine, but querying another table returns:

```
DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed
```

The source database is stored as a python tempfile:

```
ntf=tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.gdb')
```

The following is a query function.

```
def sqliteQ(string,filename):
'''                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    string= query string                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    filename= string file name                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    '''
    con=sqlite.connect(filename)
    c= con.cursor()
    c.execute(string)
    out=c.fetchall()
    c.close()
    return out
```

I am able to successfully query the database like this:

```
sq=db.sqliteQ("select sql from sqlite_master where type='table' and name='managements'", gdb.name)
In [13]: sq
Out[13]: 'CREATE TABLE managements (path varchar(255), name varchar(255), data varchar(50000), date date, owner varchar(64), password varchar(64), prot text)'
```

However the following returns the error:

```
    In[14]: m=db.sqliteQ('select * from managements', gdb.name)
    41     con=sqlite.connect(filename)
     42     c= con.cursor()
---> 43     c.execute(string)
     44     out=c.fetchall()
     45     c.close()

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlite/main.pyc in execute(self, SQL, *parms)
    242         if len(parms) == 0:
    243             # If there are no paramters, just execute the query.

--> 244             self.rs = self.con.db.execute(SQL)
    245         else:
    246             if len(parms) == 1 and \

DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed
```

I can successfully run both queries using the sqlite command line tool. Any suggestions would be most helpful.

Peter

UPDATE

It seems that I only encounter this problem when using the `tempfile`. I am downloading a .zip file and reading the enclosed sqlite database to `cStringIO` and writing to the `tempfile` using this function:

```
def tGDB (URLo):
    mem=io.StringIO(URLo.read())
    zf=zp.ZipFile(mem)
    ntf=tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.gdb')
    ntf.write(zf.read(zf.namelist()[0]))
    return ntf
```

I guess that this may indicate there is a problem with the conversion pipeline from zip to tempfile, but its quite strange that the first query works and the second doesn't.

Comment: What sqlite module are you importing?

Comment: I'm on Debian and have installed the package `python-sqlite` In [66]: sqlite.version
Out[66]: '1.0.1'

Comment: and what is the version of the sqlite client (printed when you start it)?

Comment: `SQLite version 2.8.17` the file I am using is a .gdb (sqlite2)